# What is the meaning of "I would do for a candy bar"?

Tags: meaning

I am reading Diary of Wimpy Kid (Diary of a Wimpy Kid - Book 2 - Rodrick Rules). But when I read to this page. I get stuck about like that

What is the meaning of "What I would do for a candy bar" in this situation?

We had to do the whole skit in Spanish. Rowley asked me what I would do **for a candy bar**, and I said I'd stand on my head.

Here is my research(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/candy-bar) candy bar: candy shaped like a thin brick. But It seems not to make sense for this sentence.

Would you like for explaining the meaning of this in the situation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The candy bar is payment for doing something.  When you were a kid wouldn't you have done some things in order to get a piece of candy?

Comment: What are you willing to do in exchange for a sweet reward?

Comment: Think of it as an elision of "_I don't know_ what I would do for a candy bar."

Comment: Your title includes a rhetorical question, and your text shows a question that seeks information.

Comment: I have just edited the titile. Thank you for your comment @YosefBaskin